# How to get a list of friends who has performed the same action on the same object

Tags: object, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

By using the new OG Beta, Is there a way to get a list of friends who performs the same action on the same object? For example, my action is called 'check_in' and my object is 'game'. I want to get a list of friends who are checked in to 'Game A'. Any tip would be great!

Answer (score 0):

There is no API right now but you can use the facepile social plugin to display it to your users.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think Facepile only shows friends who authorized the app. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should show all friends who have "checked_in" to your game. Even to non-authorized viewers.